# What is __sighandler_t struct and purpose of SIGTRAP signal handler

Tags: ida, anti-debugging, struct

I'm reversing an ELF x86 binary which apparently has anti-reversing/anti-debuging protections, and one of the first thing the ELF does is to call a sys_signal with a SIGTRAP value :

```
.text:08048063                 mov     eax, 48         ; sys_signal
.text:08048068                 mov     ebx, 5          ; SIGTRAP
.text:0804806D                 mov     ecx, offset sub_80480E2
.text:08048072                 int     80h             ; LINUX - sys_signal
.text:08048074                 jmp     short loc_8048077
```

I have three questions :

- First, am I right to think that the purpose of this is to create a handler for the SIGTRAP signal, probably in order to prevent any debuger use
- Second, if this is creating a SIGTRAP handler, I should find a `__sighandler_t` at `sub_80480E2`, according to [this x86 syscall table](https://github.com/Hackndo/misc/blob/master/syscalls32.md). How can I setup IDA so that it recognizes it as a __sighandler_t struct?
- Third, I could not find any detailed information about this structure. What is its composition?

I found in `signal.h` those lines :

```
/* Type of a signal handler.  */
typedef void (*__sighandler_t) (int);
```

Is __sighandler_t only a ptr to a function?

Thanks ! Feel free to tell me if I'm not beeing clear or if I forgot a usefull information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First, am I right to think that the purpose of this is to create a
>   handler for the SIGTRAP signal, probably in order to prevent any
>   debuger use

When a SIGTRAP is raised, normally the handler given in parameter of `signal` is called. If you have a debugger attached, this function will not get called.
If your handler is never called, you can assume a debugger is attached.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void on_trap(int n)
{
        puts("on_trap");
}

void callme(void)
{
        puts("hello");
        __asm__ volatile("int $0x03");
        puts("bye");
}

int main(void)
{
        signal(SIGTRAP, on_trap);
        callme();
        return 0;
}
```

Normal run:

```
$ ./antidebug
hello
on_trap
bye
```

With gdb:

```
gdb -q antidebug
Reading symbols from antidebug...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/antidebug
hello

Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x0000000008001174 in callme ()
(gdb) c
Continuing.
bye
```

> Second, if this is creating a SIGTRAP handler, I should find a
>   __sighandler_t at sub_80480E2, according to this x86 syscall table. How can I setup IDA so that it recognizes it as a __sighandler_t
>   struct?

sighandler_t is a typedef for a function pointer, not a structure.
If you want to define a memory area as a structure, you can use the shortcut `ALT+Q`.

> Third, I could not find any detailed information about this structure.
>   What is its composition?

`sub_80480E2` contains code, as mentioned this is not a structure but a function pointer.
Imagine you have the syscall `sigaction` instead, you can simply check the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) to see the structure definition.
But IDA Pro has most of structures definition from standard libraries.

> Is __sighandler_t only a ptr to a function?

Yes.